# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un ciclo en javascript que me permita hacer una acción dependiendo del checkbox que seleccione?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Lo que necesito es crear una funcion ciclica que permita saber cual de los checkbox estoy seleccionando como limite y que cuando ambos checkbox sean selecconados se sumen mostrando un total.

Una vez, dependiendo del checkbox seleccionado sirvira será el limite del input final.

Tengo puesto ya un ejemplo en el código que les dejo pero funciona solo con un input establecido de manera estatica que es el del inici.

Lo que quiero hacer es que funcione de manera más dinámica. estaría muy agredecido con sus aportaciones!

```js
//Con este código solo puedo hacer la funcion del limite con un solo numero

var contador = 0;
// AQUI obtenemos el value como número entero
var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("h1").value, 10);

function incrementar() {
   if (contador == c) {
     //como puedo concatenar el valor de c?
      alert('Maximo permitido alcanzado:' + 'lol');
   } else {
      document.form.r.value = contador++;
   }
}

function decrementar() {
  if (contador == 0) {
     alert('Minimo permitido alcanzado: 0');
  } else {
      document.form.r.value = contador--;
  }
}
```

```html
    <form name="form">
    <label>1er Limite a seleccionar</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="h1" value="5"  readonly="readonly">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <label>2ndo Limite a seleccionar</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="h2" value="10"  readonly="readonly">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>

    <label>*Nuevo Limite creado por la suma de los dos limites 
           seleccionados anteriormente*
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly="readonly">
    <br>
            <br><br>
    <label>
     ******Aquí va el el número que selecciones, 
            no olvide que el número que necesites 
            va a depender de un limite seleccionado 
            en la parte de arriba******
    </label>
      <br><br>
    <label>Limite de (1er) o (2ndo) o (ambos)                   datos 
     tomados
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="r" id="r" readonly="readonly">

    <input type="button" onClick="incrementar()" value="aumentar"> 
    <input type="button" onClick="decrementar()" value="disminuir">

     <br><br>

    
    </form>
```

Comment: puede añadir una mejor explicación de lo quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debe servirte, cada vez que seleccionas un `checkbox`, el valor limite se actualizara y con esto podrás controlar el limite según las opciones que tienes activadas.

```js
// incrementar()
  // ESTA FUNCIÓN  VERIFICA QUE EL LIMITE SEA MAYOR QUE 0
  // DESPUÉS VERIFICA QUE EL VALOR ACTUAL EN EL CAMPO SEA MENOR AL LIMITE ESTABLECIDO
  // SI EL VALOR ES MENOR, LE AUMENTA UNO AL VALOR ACTUAL
  function incrementar() {
   var currentMaxVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value, 10);
   if (currentMaxVal > 0) {
    var currentVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value, 10);
      if (currentVal < currentMaxVal) {       
         document.form.r.value = currentVal + 1;
      } else {
         alert('Maximo permitido alcanzado: ' + currentMaxVal + ' lol');
      }    
   } else {
        alert('Seleccione una opcion, el valor total debe ser mayor a 0');
   }
  }
  // decrementar()
  // ESTA FUNCIÓN REVISA EL VALOR ACTUAL Y MIENTRAS DICHO VALOR SEA MAYOR A 0
  // SE LE PUEDE RESTAR -1
  // SI EL VALOR ACTUAL NO ES MAYOR A 0 NO SE LE RESTA Y SE MANDA UN MENSAJE DE ADVERTENCIA
  // INDICANDO QUE YA SE ALCANZO EL LIMITE MÍNIMO 
  function decrementar() {     
   var currentVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value, 10);
     if (currentVal > 0) {
        document.form.r.value = currentVal - 1;
      } else {
        alert('Minimo permitido alcanzado');
      }
  }
  // setLimiter()
  // ESTA FUNCIÓN SE EJECUTA CADA VEZ QUE HAY UN CAMBIO EN LOS CHECKBOX [H1_CHECKBOX Y H2_CHECKBOX] 
  // DESPUÉS SE REVISA CUALES CHECKBOXS ESTÁN ACTIVADOS Y SE TOMA SU VALOR
  // DESPUÉS SE SUMAN LOS VALORES DE LOS CHECKBOXS ACTIVADOS
  // SE HACE UNA VALIDACIÓN YA QUE SI EL VALOR ACTUAL ES MAYOR AL LIMITE EL VALOR ACTUAL SE REDUCE AL LIMITE ACTUAL
  function setLimiter(){
   var limite = 0;
   var limiteUno = 0;
   var limiteDos = 0;
   if (document.getElementById("h1_checkbox").checked) {limiteUno = parseInt(document.getElementById("h1").value, 10);}
   if (document.getElementById("h2_checkbox").checked) {limiteDos = parseInt(document.getElementById("h2").value, 10);}
   limite = limiteUno + limiteDos;
   document.form.total.value = limite;
   var currentTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").value, 10);
   var currentLimitado = parseInt(document.getElementById("r").value, 10);
   if (currentLimitado > currentTotal) {document.form.r.value = limite;}
  }
```

```html
<form name="form">
    <label>1er Valor a seleccionar</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="h1" value="5"  readonly="readonly">
    <input type="checkbox" id="h1_checkbox" onchange="setLimiter()">
    <br>
    <label>2ndo Valor a seleccionar</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="h2" value="10"  readonly="readonly">
    <input type="checkbox" id="h2_checkbox" onchange="setLimiter()">
    <br>
    <label>Total que se muestra al seleccionar  el 1er y 2ndo dato al mismo tiempo</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total"  value="0" readonly="readonly">
    <br>
    <label>Limite de (1er) o (2ndo) o (ambos)  datos tomados
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="r" id="r" value ="0" readonly="readonly">

    <input type="button" onClick="incrementar()" value="aumentar"> 
    <input type="button" onClick="decrementar()" value="disminuir">
    </form>
```

Comment: Hermano, de verdad no sé como te voy a deber éste favor, no tienes algún libro o como es que lo hiciste?

Comment: Edito la respuesta para, ponerte que hace cada cosa

Comment: Por favor, te lo agradecería muchisimo

Comment: Listo, ya quedaron los comentarios de lo que hace cada función

Comment: Gracias de verdad, oye de pura casualidad no sabes, por ejemplo convertir un numero normal (1,2,3,...) en un día?